# Makefile: Passing command line arguments to file inside Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, command-line-arguments

Inside my Makfile I have the following,

```
smktestrun: smktest
    @../projects/test.sh
```

And I call this using:

```
Make smktestrun
```

But sometimes I need to pass an parameter/argument along with this file (test.sh)

So basically I would like:

```
test.sh -abc
```

But if i just pass the argument in the Makefile itself, the argument is not taken as simply the sheel script is executed.

So is  there a way I could specify in the Makefile that an argument needs to be passed with that file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like

```
smktestrun: smktest
        @../projects/test.sh $(TESTARGS)
```

Then call the Makefile with

```
$ make smktestrun TESTARGS="-abc"
```

Comment: Great thanks.one add-on ?. If i just call: make smktestrun, will it complain that i need the TESTARGS also?

Comment: I don't think it should, but if it does, you can just assign a default empty value inside the Makefile with `TESTARGS:=`

Answer (score 4):

You could define a variable in Makefile.

```
smktestrun: smktest
    @../projects/test.sh ${ARG}
```

Then the command line of make is:

```
make smktestrun ARG="something"
```

Comment: thanks, you have written {} @chepner wrote the same with (). are both ok to use?

Comment: There's no difference – they mean exactly the same (in GNU Make and in POSIX make). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185607/whats-the-difference-between-parenthesis-and-curly-bracket-syntax-in-ma