# What's the difference between parenthesis $() and curly bracket ${} syntax in Makefile?

Tags: variables, syntax, makefile

Is there any differences in invoking variables with syntax `${var}` and `$(var)`? For instance, in the way the variable will be expanded or anything?

Comment: I have a vague recollection that in some early version(s) of make, only parens ($(...)) would be expanded in make and *not* braces (${...}).  Variables with braces could then be used in actions where they would be expanded by the shell; the distinction might be relevant in some cases.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

There's no difference – they mean exactly the same (in GNU Make and in POSIX make).

I think that `$(round brackets)` look tidier, but that's just personal preference.

(Other answers point to the relevant sections of the GNU Make documentation, and note that you shouldn't mix the syntaxes within a single expression)

Comment: I use the `$()` in make to avoid causing myself confusion (more than already exists) between make and shell variables. [GNU Make documentation on variable references](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference).

Comment: Thanks to user @Eloy for suggesting an expansion to this answer, even though I rejected their compendium in favour of simply noting the valuable extra points in other answers.

Comment: Some tools might not honor their sameness. IntelliJ IDEA highlighted `deploy: ${DEPS}` as a syntax error for me, but showed `deploy: $(DEPS)` as correct, even though both spellings have the same effect when invoked in `make`.

Comment: The `ifeq` conditional requires use of round brackets for the equality check. You can't safely use curly braces on that line. As such, I would favour `$(round brackets)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `$()` is also valid POSIX sh family syntax, for capturing the output of a shell command as a string. I do not see in the GNU make documentation where it says curly bracket macro expansion cannot be used in ifeq.

Answer (score 65):

The [*Basics of Variable References* section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#Reference) from the `GNU make` documentation state **no differences**:

> To substitute a variable's value, write a dollar sign followed by the
>   name of the variable in parentheses or braces: **either `$(foo)` or
>   `${foo}` is a valid reference** to the variable foo.

Answer (score 27):

As already correctly pointed out, there is no difference **but** be be wary not to mix the two kind of delimiters as it can lead to cryptic errors like in the GNU make [example by **unomadh**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40737550).

From [the GNU make manual on the Function Call Syntax](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_8.html#SEC76) (emphasis mine):

> […] If the arguments themselves contain other function calls or variable references, it is wisest to use the same kind of delimiters for all the references; write `$(subst a,b,$(x))`, not `$(subst a,b,${x})`. This is because it is clearer, and **because only one type of delimiter is matched to find the end of the reference**.

Comment: Accidentally wrote and found $(call-function ${VARIABLE}) cleaner to read and write like in Bash.

Comment: As criticism of the GNU make manual: And yet the given example works perfectly fine. All of `$(subst a,b,$(x))` and `$(subst a,b,${x})` and `${subst a,b,$(x)}` and `${subst a,b,${x}}` yield the same result. The reasoning that only one delimiter is matched makes little sense--of course if a reference starts with ( it must end with ), `$(x}` is clearly wrong, but seems irrelevant to mixing syntax for _different_ references. Barring pathological cases like unomadh's where the variable name is a comma, mixing syntax seems to work.

Answer (score 19):

The ${} style lets you test the make rules in the shell, if you have the corresponding environment variables set, since that is compatible with bash.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, it seems to be fairly different:

```
, = ,
list = a,b,c
$(info $(subst $(,),-,$(list))_EOL)
$(info $(subst ${,},-,$(list))_EOL)
```

outputs

```
a-b-c_EOL
md/init-profile.md:4: *** unterminated variable reference. Stop.
```

But so far I only found this difference when the variable name into ${...} contains itself a comma. I first thought ${...} was expanding the comma not as part as the value, but it turns out i'm not able to hack it this way. I still don't understand this... If anyone had an explanation, I'd be happy to know !

Comment: Based on Edouard's answer, which notes that the GNU make documentation states there's no difference, I'd guess this could just be a bug.

Comment: As pointed out in Alexandre Perrin's answer, the two syntaxes should not be mixed in the same line.

Comment: First, obviously, don't use commas in variable names. Second, this works with all braces `${info ${subst ${,},-,${list}}_EOL}`, so it really does seem to be a bug with mixing parens and braces.

Answer (score 5):

It makes a difference if the expression contains unbalanced brackets:

```
${info ${subst ),(,:-)}}
$(info $(subst ),(,:-)))
```

->

```
:-(
*** insufficient number of arguments (1) to function 'subst'.  Stop.
```

For variable references, this makes a difference for functions, or for variable names that contain brackets (bad idea)