# make: automatic variables in pattern rule prerequisites

Tags: makefile

I'm using GNU Make on Arch Linux to generate PDFs from LilyPond source files. I have a directory structure as follows:

```
scores/
├── makefile
├── out
│   ├── others-songs
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── 失恋阵线联盟
│   │       ├── 失恋阵线联盟.edition.log
│   │       ├── 失恋阵线联盟.oll.log
│   │       └── 失恋阵线联盟.pdf
│   └── ...
├── src
│   ├── others-songs
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── 失恋阵线联盟
│   │       ├── chorus.ily
│   │       ├── verse.ily
│   │       ├── words.ily
│   │       └── 失恋阵线联盟.ly
│   └── ...
```

The PDFs in the `out` directory depend on the `.ily` and `.ly` files in the corresponding directory in `src`. The following implicit pattern rule works if the `.ly` file is modified, but not if any of the other files are:

```
LY = $(shell find src -iname '*.ly')
PDF = $(subst src,out,$(LY:.ly=.pdf))

pdf: $(PDF)
out/%.pdf: src/%.ly
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @lilypond --include=$(lib) \
             -dpoint-and-click=\#f \
             -o $(basename $@) $<
```

I tried doing several different things, like appending `$(<D)*.ily` to the prerequisites, but it wasn't successful. I've looked at the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) online for help, but I didn't come up with anything that that I was able to apply to my particular situation.

How can I write a pattern rule that makes each PDF depend on all the files in the appropriate corresponding source directory?

#### EDIT

I may not have been clear enough with my first question. The behavior I want is if any of the files in the source directories are changed, the corresponding PDF is updated. For example, if `chorus.ily` is changed, then `失恋阵线联盟.ly` is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working example:

```
LY := $(shell find src -iname '*.ly')
PDF := ${LY:src/%.ly=out/%.pdf}
pdf: $(PDF)

define pdf_deps
$(1:src/%.ly=out/%.pdf) : $(wildcard $(dir ${1})*)
endef

# Make each pdf depend on all the files in its src directory.
$(foreach ly,${LY},$(eval $(call pdf_deps,${ly})))

out/%.pdf:
    @echo "making $@ from $^"
```

Usage:

```
$ ls -1R
.:
Makefile
out
src

./out:

./src:
A
B

./src/A:
a.ly

./src/B:
b.1
b.ly

$ make
making out/B/b.pdf from src/B/b.ly src/B/b.1
mkdir -p out/B
touch out/B/b.pdf
making out/A/a.pdf from src/A/a.ly
mkdir -p out/A
touch out/A/a.pdf

$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'pdf'.

$ touch src/B/b.ly
$ make
making out/B/b.pdf from src/B/b.ly src/B/b.1
mkdir -p out/B
touch out/B/b.pdf

$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'pdf'.

$ touch src/B/b.1
$ make
making out/B/b.pdf from src/B/b.ly src/B/b.1
mkdir -p out/B
touch out/B/b.pdf

$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'pdf'.
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, this is basically making `make` write out a rule for every `.ly` file? And I was curious about curly braces versus parentheses around variables, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677986/5894001) mentions that they shouldn't be mixed. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I tested this, and it made me realize I wasn't clear in my original question. In this code, running make the first time will generate all of the PDFs, but if I later touch `b.1`, make won't detect the change, but that's the behavior I'm after. Sorry if I was confusing...

Comment: @RandyJosleyn I added a working example where `touch` of any source causes `.pdf` build.

Comment: @RandyJosleyn With regards to `$()` vs `${}`, they mean the same thing. I use the former for function calls and the latter for variables (similar to `bash`).