# Makefile crashed while making after pass the ./configure --host=mingw32

Tags: c, macos, gcc, makefile, mingw32

Everyone: situation: MacOS with x86_64-w64-mingw32 compiling toolchain I tried to compile GDB for Windows from the source code of GDB. But, after ./configure, I got

```
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wstack-usage=262144 -Wno-format -I./../zlib -Iincludedir -D__USE_MINGW_ACCESS  -release `cat libtool-soversion`  -Llibdir -Wl,--stack,12582912 -o libbfd.la -rpath /usr/local/lib archive.lo archures.lo bfd.lo bfdio.lo bfdwin.lo cache.lo coff-bfd.lo compress.lo corefile.lo elf-properties.lo format.lo hash.lo init.lo libbfd.lo linker.lo merge.lo opncls.lo reloc.lo section.lo simple.lo stab-syms.lo stabs.lo syms.lo targets.lo binary.lo ihex.lo srec.lo tekhex.lo verilog.lo `cat ofiles`   -L./../zlib -lz 
./libtool: line 5208: cd: libdir: No such file or directory
libtool: link: cannot determine absolute directory name of `libdir'
make[4]: *** [libbfd.la] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-bfd] Error 2
```

I am sure my MingW32 is fully built and capable.

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-addr2line   x86_64-w64-mingw32-dllwrap     x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ranlib  x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld.bfd      x86_64-w64-mingw32-size
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar          x86_64-w64-mingw32-elfedit     x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcov        x86_64-w64-mingw32-lto-dump    x86_64-w64-mingw32-strings
x86_64-w64-mingw32-as          x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++         x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcov-dump   x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm          x86_64-w64-mingw32-strip
x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++         x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc         x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcov-tool   x86_64-w64-mingw32-objcopy     x86_64-w64-mingw32-windmc
x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++filt     x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-10.2.0  x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran    x86_64-w64-mingw32-objdump     x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres
x86_64-w64-mingw32-cpp         x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar      x86_64-w64-mingw32-gprof       x86_64-w64-mingw32-ranlib      
x86_64-w64-mingw32-dlltool     x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-nm      x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld          x86_64-w64-mingw32-readelf
```

I install it via HomeBrew And here is the config for libdir in my Makefile

```
prefix = /usr/local
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
LDFLAGS = -Llibdir
...
    "libdir=$(libdir)" \
...
```

Totally have no idea how to fix this. Any idea? Or if you need some more information to figure it out, just let me know.

And just download the source code of GDB, I think you could duplicate the same scenario.

```
./libtool: line 5208: cd: libdir: No such file or directory
libtool: link: cannot determine absolute directory name of `libdir'
make[4]: *** [libbfd.la] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-bfd] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you check that the directory `libdir` exists? The error message is clear about that: The tool `libtool` does not find it. -- BTW, it is not the Makefile that crashes, actually no program crashes. It is the program `libtool` that gracefully and correctly exits with an error message, and the program `make` forwards this message to you and stops the process, also correctly. Please be exact with your wording.

Comment: @thebusybee Yes, I did. And the libtool was provided/generated by make command. libdir was just a environment variable which is defined by Makefile.

Comment: As the command line and error message say, you give `libtool` not the right path. The command line contains `-Llibdir` and the error message says "cannot determine absolute directory name of 'libdir'". What happens if you correct your Makefile and write `LDFLAGS = -L${libdir}`? (Or, as I would use "make": `LDFLAGS = -L$(libdir)` with parentheses instead of curly braces.)

Comment: @thebusybee I know, I don't think it should be -L$(libdir), cuz libdir is only a plain path. I don't think it would work, but anyway, I will give a try for ${}.

Comment: @thebusybee OMG, I think you hit the point!

Comment: @thebusybee OMG, that is great !!!!! But I never expect that Makefile could expose such kind of flaw. It literally appeared as '-Llibdir' in my Makefile! How could that be possible?!

Comment: I have written an answer. Please mark it. ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the command line and error message say, you give libtool not the right path.

The command line contains `-Llibdir` and the error message says "cannot determine absolute directory name of 'libdir'".

So you wrote your Makefile to use `libdir` literally and not as the variable as it should be. Change it into:

```
LDFLAGS = -L$(libdir)
```

or

```
LDFLAGS = -L${libdir}
```

There is no real difference between parentheses and braces, just don't mix them up. Helpful links are:
[The difference between parentheses and curly braces in GNU Make](https://blog.jgc.org/2020/06/the-difference-between-parentheses-and.html) and
[What's the difference between parenthesis $() and curly bracket ${} syntax in Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185607/whats-the-difference-between-parenthesis-and-curly-bracket-syntax-in-ma)

Comment: Wrong! It should be -L${} in terms of the rigorous meaning on -L${}, but maybe it works still by using -L$(), but it should be -L${}

Comment: @Edee Please check if the edit calms you. Else please detail what you mean by "rigorous meaning".

Comment: rigorous meaning means that there is a clear difference between ${} and $(), no real difference really depends on the mis-using cases, in most of the case, $() will work just like ${} doesn't mean they could work identically under any circumstances.