# Issue converting makefile scripts into gitlab-ci.yml scripts

Tags: makefile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm trying to move a script from a makefile into a gitlab yml file.

In the makefile, there are commands that call environment variables as $(VAR). If I move this line into the yml file as part of a script for a stage, how do I alter this line to work in gitlab yml?

Thank you!

I tried looking up information about gitlab yml variables, but I can only find information about ${VAR} and $VAR in yml.

Comment: In a makefile, `$(VAR)` expands a *make* variable.  These can come from the environment, but they are more often defined (only) in the makefile itself.

Answer (score 0):

In makefiles (at least in the POSIX and GNU dialects) the `$(VAR)` and `${VAR}` syntax [mean the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185607/whats-the-difference-between-parenthesis-and-curly-bracket-syntax-in-ma): variable expansion.

In `.gitlab-ci.yml`, you need to [use `$VAR`, `${VAR}`, or `%VAR%` for variable expansion](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#gitlab-internal-variable-expansion-mechanism).

So you can convert from `$(VAR)` in a `Makefile` to `${VAR}` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.