# Pass CLI Argument to LUA File with Makefile

Tags: makefile, lua, command-line-interface

I realize this is trivial and I probably just haven't had enough coffee yet this morning but my question is as follows! How can I pass an argument to my init.lua file through my Makefile? My goal is to be able to declare the hostname of my ESP/NodeMCU in the command line at the time of uploading my files to the device.

I realize that is is easy enough to adjust my lua file for each device but since I only want to pass a single argument, and never anymore, I was hoping I could do it along with my CLI command. I tried the answer from [Makefile: Passing command line arguments to file inside Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500204/makefile-passing-command-line-arguments-to-file-inside-makefile) but I get an Error 2. The issue is because in order to set the host name, in a normal lua file, there are parentheses involved. The normal command for setting the hostname is:

```
wifi.sta.sethostname("somehostname")
```

So according to the link I posted I have to run my command as follows:

```
make upload_all HNAME="wifi.sta.sethostname("somehostname")"
```

which throws out the syntax error. What is the best approach to getting around this? Can I use a variable to declare the wifi.sta.sethostname portion? I tried but probably not doing it right. I'm not a scripting guru but I can usually find my way around pretty well. Thanks in advance!

Updated to include some code from Makefile!

```
@python $(NODEMCU-COMMAND) $(foreach f, $^, $(f)) $(HNAME)
```

I wonder if it is even possible. I realize now that I need it to be on a new line when it is interacting with the ESP. Not sure if I can somehow append the newline, ('/n'), to my Makefile line.

Thanks to @EgorSkriptunoff I managed to at least get rid of the error. However it doesn't do anything on the actual device. I've since realized that once the device is reset, if that line isn't in actual code on the device, it goes back to the default hostname. The only solution I can see is to possibly append the init.lua file from the CLI which probably won't work either.

Comment: You are using the same delimiters twice, maybe try `make upload_all HNAME="wifi.sta.sethostname('somehostname')"`?  Can't test right now so just an idea

Comment: I tested it and still same syntax error. I even tried make 'upload_all HNAME='wifi.sta.sethostname("somehostname")'' and no go. I wonder if it has to do with the actual code in my Makefile. I'll update my post with that info.

Comment: Where does "Error 2" come from: from makefile or from Python?  What is the line# where the error is raised? How `$(HNAME)` parameter is used inside Python script?  Does Python script really expect this parameter to be a chunk of Lua code?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff The Error 2 comes from the line in the Makefile that i posted in my question. Python is just used to load the lua files onto the ESP/NodeMCU.

Comment: @ToddCoplien - Error 2 can imply anything.  What is the error text?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Right. Sorry. The actual error is: 
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Makefile:33: recipe for target 'upload_all' failed
make: *** [upload_all] Error 2

Comment: @ToddCoplien - Try `make upload_all HNAME="wifi.sta.sethostname'somehostname'"` - it does not contain parentheses